# Opayo Form Integration: Failed payment being reported as success

Tags: opayo

We are developers using the Opayo Form (previously known as Sage Pay Form) integration to accept payments.  At least two of our customers have reported an issue where a payment is reported successful by our product, but is ultimately rejected due to "the number of authorisation attempts exceeds the limit".

We believe that Opayo Form is errantly routing back to our success URL rather than the failure URL after this specific payment failure type.  All other payment failure types correctly route back to the failure URL.

[A screenshot from our Spindle product illustrates this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQNhG.png)

[This is what is seen for this transaction in the Opayo account portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJlcL.png)

We would very much appreciate any assistance on how we can resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues on Opayo Direct, where I randomly get 2 callbacks within fractions of a second of each other.  The second authorisation check basically invalidates the successful one.  My solution (which works probably 19 out of 20 times) is to check the status of the order and to have a short-term cache of the results from Opayo.  In truth it's not ideal, but I've not been able to find any commonality to pass over to Opayo to investigate.